# Facebook Graph SDK create video post using URL

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to use URL as a video source to create a video post on Facebook using facebook's PHP SDK for graph API. I am trying to use `uploadVideo` method from the example given on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_upload_video/

This method gives error

`filesize(): stat failed for <URL>`

It is trying to read file by using `filesize()` and it is not possible to use URL as the source.

The problem is while making the POST request to Facebook I have only access to the video URL and it will not be feasible to download on the local machine and post it to Facebook.

So is there other methods to use URL to post a video to Facebook?

Answer (score 0):

After going through the source code for PHP SDK and how the `uploadVideo` method work. I found 'videoToUpload' method.

```
      $response = $facebook->post('/'.$fb_page_id.'/videos', array(
        'description' => $postData['description'],
        'source'      => $facebook->videoToUpload($media)
    ), $access_token);
```

This method works. But I am not sure if this is the right way to go.

Comment: Well if it works, and does the thing you need it to …? I think this _will_ effectively “download” the data to your server and then send it to the API from there though, if you dive into the SDK code a bit, you see `fopen` and `stream_get_contents` get involved, so this will basically be using the HTTP wrapper functionality, when used with a URL.

Comment: Yes, I saw it actually on `FacebookFile` class on `open` method
`  $this->stream = fopen($this->path, 'r');` 

I could not find any other working method for my scenario.